# How to disable Named imports must be alphabetized - tslint

Tags: tslint

How to disable Named imports must be alphabetized - tslint ?

I am getting error:

**Named imports must be alphabetized.**

I don't know how to disable this error.

My **tsconfig.json** configuration is:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "outDir": "build/dist",
        "module": "esnext",
        "target": "es5",
        "lib": [
            "es6",
            "dom"
        ],
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowJs": true,
        "jsx": "react",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "rootDir": "src",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noImplicitThis": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "strictNullChecks": false,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
        "noUnusedLocals": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "build",
        "scripts",
        "acceptance-tests",
        "webpack",
        "jest",
        "src/setupTests.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 19):

Open `tslint.json` and add `ordered-imports` to `rules` and restart the server (npm) if is running.

```
"rules": {
  "ordered-imports": false
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From this [Rule of ordered-imports](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/ordered-imports/)

> Named imports must be alphabetized (i.e. “import {A, B, C} from
>   “foo”;”)
>
> - The exact ordering can be controlled by the named-imports-order    option.
> - “longName as name” imports are ordered by “longName”.

Add this line to your `tsconfig` file:

```
"rules": {
    "named-imports-order": "any"
 }
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: error TS5023: Unknown compiler option 'named-imports-order'.

Comment: see if [this link](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-tslint/issues/148) helps you. Also, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Unknown compiler option 'ordered-imports'.
Any help?

Answer (score 1):

`"ordered-imports": false,` works for me in VS Code.